# Same code for two jtables but one of them isn't getting values from SQL table

Tags: java, sql, netbeans-8

Kindly help me to solve this problem, also tell me how to display data on the table by using condition on comboBox. Following is the code and Output. Please help me, as I have to show this to my instructor tomorrow.

```
public ArrayList<User> userList() {
    ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=DB_Project;user=User;Password=password";
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Income";
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(query);
        User user;
        while(rs.next()){
            user= new User(rs.getInt("Amout"),rs.getString("Date"),rs.getString("Source"));
            usersList.add(user);          
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    return usersList;
    }
public void show_user() {
    ArrayList<User> list = userList();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)Income_Table.getModel();
    Object[] row =new Object[3];
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        row[0]=list.get(i).getAmout();
        row[1]=list.get(i).getDate();
        row[2]=list.get(i).getSource();
        model.addRow(row);
    }
}

//**********tbl_Expense
public ArrayList<User_E> userList_E() {
    ArrayList<User_E> UsersList_E = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String eurl="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=DB_Project;user=User;Password=password";
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(eurl);
        String query_E = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Expense";
        Statement stt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst= stt.executeQuery(query_E);
        User_E user_e;
        while(rst.next()){
            user_e = new User_E(rst.getString("ExpenseDetail"),rst.getString("Category"),rst.getString("Date"),rst.getInt("Amount"));
            UsersList_E.add(user_e);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    return UsersList_E;
}
public void showuser_E(){
    ArrayList<User_E> list_E = userList_E();
    DefaultTableModel model_e = (DefaultTableModel)Expense_Table.getModel();
    Object[] row_e =new Object[4];
    for(int i=0;i<list_E.size();i++){
        row_e[0]=list_E.get(i).getAmount();
        row_e[1]=list_E.get(i).getDate();
        row_e[2]=list_E.get(i).getCategory();
        row_e[3]=list_E.get(i).getExpenseDetail();
        model_e.addRow(row_e);
    }
}
```

[This is the Output, getting 0 instead of original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMRdU.png)

Comment: Did you check if there is any data in the `tbl_Expense` table?

Comment: Yes, data is there in tbl_Expense table. The reason, the table was not being displayed was a NULL entry in the table.

Comment: Glad you are able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One hideous thing: nothing is closed (connection, statement, result set).
Try-with-resources may help here, to automatically close those, even on return, break, raised exception.

```
public ArrayList<User_E> userList_E() {
    ArrayList<User_E> usersList_E = new ArrayList<>();
    String eurl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=DB_Project;"
        + "user=User;Password=password";
    String query_E = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Expense";
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(eurl);
            Statement stt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rst= stt.executeQuery(query_E)) {
        while(rst.next()){
            User user_e = new User_E(rst.getString("ExpenseDetail"),
                                     rst.getString("Category"),
                                     rst.getString("Date"),
                                     rst.getInt("Amount"));
            usersList_E.add(user_e);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
    return usersList_E;
}
```

Class.forName on the driver class is since years no longer required.

For the error: I can only assume that the application is running out of free connections.

Comment: I had `getConnection(eurl));` with two `)`s. Sorry for that. If you mean, it still does not solve the error, I have no idea, everything else seems quite okay to me.

Comment: There was no error in the code. The table was not being displayed just because one entry in the table was NULL, I removed that entry after that the table was displayed. Thanx for your time.

Comment: One solution would be to do after every `getString` a check on `rst.wasNull()`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what the issue by looking at the code posted. But, the application's  database access, querying and showing the data in the GUI need to be structured something like this:

**1. Access database and get connection:**
Get connection object for the database `DB_Project` (there is no need to create connection objects twice).

**2. Query 1:**

- Create statement
- Query the `tbl_Income` table and populate the "userList"
- Close the statement (this also closes the corresponding result set)

**3. Query 2:**

- Create statement
- Query the `tbl_Expense` table and populate the "userList_E"
- Close the statement

**4. Close connection** (this is optional and depends on application requirement).

**5. Display GUI using the queried data:**

- Show user income `JTable` using the "userList"
- Show user expense `JTable` using the "userList_E"

**NOTES:**

Place some debug or log statements in the Java code and verify if there is any data in the tables being queried and also what kind of data it is. Querying the database tables directly and interactively or from the command prompt also helps. Also, after populating the list collections print the lists onto the console using `System.out.prinltln()` statements to verify if the data is populated to them properly.

**How to display based on combo box selection:**

Here is the link to [Java tutorials on using Swing JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) - see the section "Handling Events on a Combo Box".

There are different ways one can build the code to acheive this functionality.

1. By directly querying the database table using the data selected from
   the combo box, or
2. By filtering the data from the "list" data already queried and populated to it. This option requires the queried data from the database tables be stored in instance variables.

Again, it depends upon the application requirement. In case the database table data is not changing then option 2 is the correct method, otherwise query the database table directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed guidance.